# How to force godoc on shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut, godoc

I got a couple of questions regarding Go plugin in VSCode and decided to merge it to one:

1. Can't find any info if it is possible to force show godoc popup via a shortcut instead of mouse hover - is it possible ?
2. Is there any way to show godoc popup when going through the code completion window ?

thanks